# Creating colums with flexbox

Tags: css

I have a div and inside two headings and then several parapraphs. Unfortunately, I can neither change the HTML, nor use JS to create some kind of additional container around the paragraphs. The solution has to be in CSS. So I ask: Is that possible?

The number of paragraphs within the div may change, the length of content too. What I want is, that the content organizes itselve in a two-columns layout. The two headings should be in the left column (30%), the remaining paragraphs should be in the second column (70%).

With float it only works as long "both columns are more or less of the same height.  With flexbox I see no results, "grid" makes no sense, because it is not a grid, but some kind of artificial columns.

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <h2>...Headimg...</h2>
 <h3>...Subline...</h3>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
</div><!-wrapper-->
```

Any ideas? Somehow I think it must be possible with flexbox, but I do not see any solutions.

Comment: Have you tried using column-count? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is CSS-Grid but this may not be ideal depending on your content.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr;
  gap: .25em;
}

* {
  padding: .25em;
}

#wrapper * {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

h2,
h3 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

p {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>...Heading...</h2>
  <h3>...Subline...</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus, ipsum ipsa dolores accusamus excepturi nemo sequi laboriosam magni fuga perspiciatis quas. Omnis numquam sint ad, necessitatibus rem tempora aliquam quisquam assumenda eum quaerat
    dicta? Soluta?</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
  <p>...some text here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is quite good, but the subline is always on the same height as is the second parapraph. That is why I thought of a solution with flexbox instead of grid. But with flexbox I would need to make the height of the subline until the bottom of the coantainer and theen alle the paragraphs would go the the second column.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want is not suited to flexbox or CSS-Grid. Temani has several ideas but not being able to change the HTML or javacript is leaving you with few options.

Comment: Yes I see. So I will have to retihnk it. I was sure that it is possible with flexbox-CSS. But as we found out now, there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

`float` and `position:absolute` can approximate it. The only drawback is that you need to know the height of the `h2`

```css
#wrapper {
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:auto;
  position:relative;
}
#wrapper h3 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:30%;
  top:22px; /* this need to be manually set */
  padding:5px 0;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#wrapper h2 {
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width:30%;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 0;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#wrapper p {
  float:right;
  width:70%;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 0;
  border:1px solid green;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <h2>...Headimg...</h2>
 <h3>...Subline...</h3>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
</div>
```

Or a combination using `inline-block`, `float` and `text-align`

```css
#wrapper {
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:auto;
  text-align:right;
}

#wrapper h2,
#wrapper h3{
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width:30%;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 0;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:left;
}

#wrapper p {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
  width:70%;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 0;
  border:1px solid green;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <h2>...Headimg tile...</h2>
 <h3>...Sub line...</h3>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
 <p>...some text here...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. As the devices may cahnge, the h2 might need more then on line and then the height is different. Also the height of the font changes with the devices.

Comment: @rabo added another idea, refresh